# Mouse Scroll Wheel does not scroll in *some* Excel worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse

I am using Excel (MS 365 MSO version 2205, 64-bit) in 64-bit Windows 10; and recently (seemingly at random) my mouse wheel has stopped working in certain spreadsheets (by which I mean: certain sheets within a workbook). One such affected workbook suddenly started only allowing scrolling on one of the sheets, but not others - no amount of restarting Excel or checking Scroll Lock is off (by putting it on and off again) has worked.
Freeze Panes on the top row is on on all sheets (those that scroll and those that don't), but I have tried flipping this off to no avail.
Is anyone aware of a sheet-level scroll-lock setting anywhere, that could have been set somehow?

I have obviously not deliberately changed anything, it seems to have happened spontaneously with some Excel/Windows update. Other applications (Outlook, Edge, Word) all seem unaffected.

Finally, I have checked the other obvious things like making sure I am not editing a cell formula or running a macro etc. This behaviour occurs as soon as a file is opened.

Edit: one more maybe-relevant detail is that in the only persistent case I can find, the affected sheets all have rows ~500 onwards Hidden, and they are not recoverable (no amount of Unhide can make those bottom rows come back). If I hide the bottom rows on any new sheet, I am able to Unhide again, but not on these weird sheets.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you test this behavior with these specific sheets on a different computer? This will rule out a problem with excel vs the sheet itself.

Comment: Good idea, LPChip - a colleague is able to open that same persistently problematic file and can scroll with no issues, but he still cannot unhide those bottom rows on the affected sheets. I note that he is using version 2108 of Excel, as my machine was recently updated - perhaps a bug that will get fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed this as well (scrolling with the scroll wheel does not work, but manually dragging the scroll bar does).
Only with specific sheets in a Workbook, when all further rows have been hidden.  Like your colleague, when I tried to unhide the rows at the bottom of the sheet, they did not become visible, and I still couldn't scroll.  However, after I clicked Unhide (with the rows still selected) if I *resize the height of those rows*, they all show up and suddenly, I can scroll the worksheet again!

This is on a template file that we use to load data, and we've hidden rows like this for years.  Not sure what update caused this behavior to change, but when I resize the height of the hidden rows at the bottom of the sheet, scrolling starts working again

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, although this isn't a total fix, it is at least a solid workaround! I was able to replicate your steps of Unhide -> Row Height Change to fix affected worksheets.
I think I may leave the bottom rows unhidden for now, if this is going to be easier than waiting for the sheets to break again!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this problem is random recently and only targets partial worksheets, which is difficult to find out the specific cause, a basic way is to roll back the version of Office before the problem occurs, which requires you to use the Office deployment tool and the configuration .xml.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: try selecting all, unfreeze panes.

Hi,
this happened to me recently. Symptoms were an Excel spreadsheet, in which scrolling suddenly became disabled on the document and reopening it would not solve the problem.
I eventually went through the freeze pane option and disabled freeze entirely. It completely unlocked the spreadsheet.

Of course, I can't recall setting a freeze on the sheet at any time, maybe I did so unwillingly through a keyboard shortcut...

Comment: Where can you find this "unfreeze panes" procedure?